# AngularJS model does not update after manual change of option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with AngularJS model. Currently I have two select tags and I fill it by some async action then I just set select tag model by received data. Everything works well but if I change select tag (option) manually then model can't be changed anymore by this async actions - script keeps model picked by me manually - I am sure that I assign proper data to model from server response, because it works untill I don't change it manually...

```
<select ng-model="sModel" ng-change="changeAction(sModel)" name="sList" id="sList" ng-options="s.name for s in sList track by s.sId"></select>
```

(second select looks like above).

If someone have some idea why ngModel can't be updated after manual changes, please reply :)

Comment: Sounds like a scoping issue, do you have nested controllers?

Comment: Could you provide a reproductible case with some more code?

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem. Where's the javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You must be using ng model with direct variables. When using ngmodel with html input types use object types in ng model else value does not reflect.

```
$scope.req={value:""};
```

in html use

```
<select data-ng-model="req.value"></select>
```

Comment: Do not use direct variables use json objects like i shown above . Try it out

Comment: Sorry, I have JSON format from server response. I can't use direct variables because ng-model is picking by ng-options data, and much more details in applications are connected with it.
I  am wondering how is it possible. Auto or Manual changing is exactly the same action, data etc..

Answer (score 0):

Weird but I fixed it - It was because 'select' was wrapped by div which had ng-controller. Controller contains actually one action with change select option. After remove this ng-change it didn't help but removing whole controller declaration did..

```
<div ng-controller="sController">
<select ng-model="sModel" ng-change="changeAction(sModel)" name="sList" id="sList" ng-options="s.name for s in sList track by s.sId"></select>
</div>
```

Someone can explain me this anomaly ? ;/ Model always was changed in main/common controller (parent) where also was initially created.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/nkr33bo0/
```